# What items were made by the dwarves for the Norse gods?

Tags: norse, god-items

On the Wikipage of Mjölnir, it is said to be made by the dwarves Eitri and Brokkr. Wikipedia also states that they created other items for the gods. Those items being: Skidbladnir, the ship of Freyr, Mjölnir, Draupnir and Gungnir.

Wiki Quotes:

> "the Sons of Ivaldi are a group of dwarfs who fashion Skidbladnir, the ship of Freyr, and the Gungnir, the spear of Odin, as well as golden hair for Sif to replace what Loki had cut off."
>
> "Eitri succeeded in making the golden boar Gullinbursti, the golden ring Draupnir, and the hammer Mjöllnir."

My question being, are there any other items that the dwarves made for the gods of the Norse mythology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects mentioned in your question were created by Eitri and Brokkr, and the Sons of Ivaldi. However, there are more objects that exist which were crafted by the dwarves. You can find a list of objects belonging to Norse deities here:

### [**Viking Mythology**](http://www.viking-mythology.com/items.php)

### [**Timeless Myth**](http://www.timelessmyths.com/norse/objects.html)

Most of the objects mentioned in the list were created by the Dwarf craftsmen.

Answer (score 4):

It's not magical, but the Svartálfar is also made Sif's hair.

From Faulkes' translation<sup>1</sup> (via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sk%C3%AD%C3%B0bla%C3%B0nir)):

> In chapter 96, a myth explaining *Skíðblaðnir's* creation is provided. The chapter details that the god Loki once cut off the goddess's Sif's hair in an act of mischief. Sif's husband, Thor, enraged, found Loki, caught hold of him, and threatened to break every last bone in his body. Loki promises to have the Svartálfar make Sif a new head of hair that will grow just as any other. Loki goes to the dwarfs known as Ivaldi's sons, and they made not only Sif a new head of gold hair but also Skíðblaðnir and the spear Gungnir.

<sup>1</sup> Faulkes, Anthony (Trans.) (1995). Edda. Everyman.

Answer (score 2):

Dain and his brother Nabbi, created the magical boar named **Hildisvini** Freyja rides this boar.

Alfrigg and Berling and Dvalin and Grerr created the **Brisingamen** (A Golden Necklace) for the goddess Freyja.

Andvare created the cursed ring, **Andvarenaut**, he was robbed by Loki. The cursed ring had the same abilities as **Draupnir** however, the ring was cursed and 
would always cast a great curse on the owner, and bring misery, bad luck, and make the owner unhappy.

Eitri and Brokkr as well as creating **Draupnir** and **Mjolnir** also created **Gullinbursti** which was a boar with golden bristles that glowed in the dark.

Fjalar and Dalar killed Kvasir to gain his wisdom turning his blood into the **mead of poetry**.

The sons of Ivaldi created **Skidbladnir** for Freyr.

Sources:

1. [Timeless Myths](http://www.timelessmyths.com/norse/objects.html)
2. [Viking Mythology](http://www.viking-mythology.com/dwarfs.php)
3. [Historum](http://historum.com/art-cultural-history/49819-norse-mythology-dwarf-dwarf-legends-how-they-mixed-norse-gods.html)